# MATLAB: Index out of bounds error

Tags: matlab, indexing, bounds

```
    clear all; clc;
% Constants
width=12*0.0254; %Conversion: 1 inch = 0.0254 meters
thickness=0.5*0.0254;
length=16*0.0254;
gravity=9.81;
temp_i=293;
temp_r=293:473;
sigma=5.67*(10^-8);
temp_film=(temp_i+temp_r)/2; %Temp at convection boundary layer
beta=1./temp_film;
pr=0.713; %Prandtl number
v=15.09*(10^-6); %m^2/s
k=0.02564;
k_steel=60.5; 
cp_steel=460;
denstity_steel=7845;
volume=length*width*thickness;
area=2*length*width;
x=volume/area;

%% Calculations
Ra_bottom=(gravity.*beta.*(temp_r-temp_i).*(length.*(1./16))^3.*pr)./(v^2);
psi_Pr=(1+(.492./pr).^(9./16))^(-16./9);
Nu_bottom=0.68+0.503.*[(Ra_bottom.*psi_Pr).^(1./4)];
h_bottom=(k./length).*Nu_bottom;

%Initial values to set up loops and evaluate temp. change over time.
  i=0;
  t_bottom1=473; %Assume all parts of plate start at 200C
  t_middle1=473;
  t_top1=473;
  dt1=15;
  l=dt1;


%Evaluating temperature at bottom (t_bottom)
while t_bottom1 > 294 %294 is t_inf (20C) times 1.05 (21) in Kelvin (294K)
    i=i+1;
    l=l+dt1;
    h_bottom1=h_bottom(i)+sigma.*(t_bottom1.^4-temp_i^4)./(t_bottom1-temp_i); %Error Occurs here LINE: 41
    t_bottom1=(t_bottom1-temp_i).*exp(-h_bottom1.*dt1/(denstity_steel.*cp_steel.*volume))+293;
    y_bottom(i)=t_bottom1; %temp in K
    x_bottom(i)=l;
end
```

**Error:**

Attempted to access h_bottom(182); index out of bounds because numel(h_bottom)=181.

Error in Untitled9 (line 41)
    h_bottom1=h_bottom(i)+sigma.*(t_bottom1.^4-temp_i^4)./(t_bottom1-temp_i);

I know why this occuring, but I am having difficulties solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course the error is because you access `h_botton(182)` when `size(h_bottom,1)` is `181`.
You should check the condition of the while loop (t_bottom1 is 298,... in that moment, not smaller so the condition is fulfilled), so it never goes beyond 181. I don't know what exactly do you want to do here but the problem is exactly there.

When the matlab code gives an error it has executed until that line, so you can actually see the values of the variables in the exact moment of the error. for that just type the name of the variable in the command line, or see the workspace. This will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's OK to do, but if you define

```
temp_r = 293:0.5:473;
```

you'll have twice as many elements in `h_bottom`, which at least makes the error go away. However, it's up to you to decide whether the underlying physics then still make sense.